# How to write this function efficiently?

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose I am writing function `foo: Seq[B] => Boolean` like this:

```
case class B(xs: Seq[Int])

def foo(bs: Seq[B]): Boolean = bs.map(_.xs.size).sum > 0
```

The implementation above is *suboptimal* (since it's not necessary to loop over all `bs` elements to return `true`). How would you implement `foo` *efficiently*  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for `0` this is kind of trivial:

```
bs.exists(!_.xs.isEmpty)
```

does the job, because as soon as you find a non-empty `xs`, you are done.

Now, suppose that the threshold is not trivial, e.g. 42 instead of 0.

You can then take the iterator of `bs`, incrementally aggregate the values using `scanLeft`, and then check whether there `exists` an intermediate result that is greater than zero:

```
def foo(bs: Seq[Int]): Boolean = bs
 .iterator
 .scanLeft(0)(_ + _.xs.size)
 .exists(_ > 42)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I have two-level structure ? Suppose I've got `case class A(bs: Seq[B])` and write `foo: A => Boolean`.

Comment: @Michael Since [`Iterator`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Iterator.html#flatMap[B](f:A=%3Escala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]):Iterator[B]) has [`flatMap`](http://www.flatmapthatshit.com/), you should be able to do something like `as.iterator.flatMap(_.bs.iterator).scanLeft(0)(_ + _.xs.size).exists(_ > thr)`, and the whole construct would still unfold lazily only those entries that are actually needed.

Comment: Oh, nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question: how to write a test to make sure `foo` works lazily ? (maybe I should ask a new question about it).

Comment: @Michael Generalize the method from `Int` to a more general type argument `A`. Write a test with `A = () => Int`, where first few `() => Int` indeed return integers that sum up to a value larger than threshold, but later `() => Int` being "traps" that throw errors when invoked. Run the method. If it returns `true` without activating any "traps", then you can see that the method is lazy.

Comment: @Michael It's as if you were placing 30, 40, 50 cookies in the first three jars, and a hand-grenade with a removed safety pin in the fourth jar, and then asking your robot friend to check whether there are at least 100 cookies in the jars. If it returns `120 > 100 = true` after opening only the first three jars, it's lazy. If it opens the fourth jar and activates the grenade, it's eager (too eager...).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.